# How to solve this issue: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, onactivityresult

I´m trying to put `setResult` in adapter class, but I get the following error:

> `Error:(79, 59)` error: constructor `ActivityAdapter` in class
>   `ActivityAdapter` cannot be applied to given types;
>
> required: `MainActivity,Context,ArrayList<Adicional>`
>
> found: `Context,ArrayList<Adicional>`
>
> reason: actual and formal argument lists
>   differ in length.

I include some parameters in viewholder and after this occurred errors. Sorry about my English.

```
My Activity
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView rvAdicional;
    String idComidaad, addic;
    final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity);

        rvAdicional = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.t1_1_1_1recyclerview);
        rvAdicional.setHasFixedSize(true);

        LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        rvAdicional.setLayoutManager(manager);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if(intent != null) {
            Bundle params = intent.getExtras();
            if (params != null) {
                idComidaad = getIntent().getExtras().getString("CMD");

                String addd = params.getString("A1_1_1QTD");
                TextView addtv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewttt);

                addtv.setText(addd);

       /* if (getIntent().getSerializableExtra("RESTAURANTE_INTENTI") != null) {*/

                // Comida selectedRestaurante = (Comida) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("RESTAURANTE");
                //Comida selectedRestaurante = (Comida) intent.getSerializableExtra("RESTAURANTE");
                String url3 = "http://192.168.1.38:8085/apeti/adicional.php?id=" + idComidaad;
                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                        url3,
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {
                                Log.d(TAG, response);

                                ArrayList<Adicional> adicionalList = new JsonConverter<Adicional>()
                                        .toArrayList(response, Adicional.class);

                                 Adapter adapter = new  Adapter(getApplicationContext(), adicionalList);

                                rvAdicional.setAdapter(adapter);

                            }
                        },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                if (error != null) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, error.toString());
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Alguma coisa deu errado com a sua requisição.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                );
                MySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
            }
        }
        }
    @Override
    protected  void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        finish();
    }
}
```

Adapter:

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Adicional> itemList;

    private MainActivity mActivity;

    public Adapter(MainActivity mActivity, Context context, ArrayList<Adicional> itemList){
        this.context = context;
        this.itemList = itemList;

        this.mActivity= mActivity;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = inflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.card, parent, false);

        MyViewHolder itemViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view,mActivity);
        return itemViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
      final Adicional adicional = itemList.get(position);

        holder.tvAdicional.setText(adicional.adicional);
        holder.tvPreco.setText((String.format("R$ %.2f",adicional.valorad)).toString().replace(".",","));
        holder.idCmd.setText(adicional.idrestaurante);

        holder.current_number = 0;

        holder.tvQtdcd.setText("" + holder.current_number);

      holder.addItemcd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (holder.current_number < 10) {
                    holder.current_number++;
                }
                holder.tvQtdcd.setText("" + holder.current_number);
            }
        });

        holder.removeItemcd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (holder.current_number > 0) {
                    holder.current_number--;
                }
                holder.tvQtdcd.setText("" + holder.current_number);
            }
        });

        holder.btnadd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(holder.current_number == 0){
                    Toast.makeText(context,"Selecione a quantidade para o adicional desejado",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
                else{

                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.putExtra("msg", "Aceitou");

                    mActivity.setResult(1, intent);
                    mActivity.finish();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if(itemList != null){
            return itemList.size();
        }
        return 0;
    }



    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public CardView cvItem;
        public TextView tvAdicional; public TextView tvPreco; public TextView idCmd; public TextView addItemcd; public TextView removeItemcd; public TextView tvQtdcd;
        public Button btnadd;

        int current_number;

        private MainActivity mActivity;
        public MyViewHolder(View itemView, MainActivity mActivity) {
            super(itemView);
            cvItem = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.t1_1_1_1card_view);
            tvAdicional = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.t1_1_1_1addcard);
            tvPreco = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.t1_1_1_1precocard);
            addItemcd =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.add_itemcard);
            removeItemcd  =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.remove_itemcard);
            tvQtdcd = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iteam_amountcard);
            idCmd = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvidcmdd);
            btnadd = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.t1_1_1_1btnadd);

            this.mActivity=mActivity;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You given wrong parameter in your adapter class constructer.

Change Below line in your MainActivity Class:

```
Adapter adapter = new  Adapter(MainActivity,getApplicationContext(), adicionalList);
```